# How to replace escape character (\') from json data using sql query?

Tags: sql, json, oracle

json_data = `{"jobId":"7f","created":"2020-05-24T00:22:55.705373Z","updated":"2020-05-24T00:31:03.716279Z","status":"DONE","sha265sum":"d3adf4466b5c88027478e4c","result":"FAILED","errors":[{"errorCode":"S_ERROR","errorDetail":"In: Can\'t create in vms : Error when sending ing s request:INTERNAL: PreparedStatementCallback; Duplicate entry \'Mob 66 The L\' for key \'uc\'; nested exception is Violation Exception: Duplicate entry \'Mob 66 The L\' for key \'uc\'","sId":47}`

I want to replace (\')  with empty char in the above data, using oracle sql query; i am trying to use

select replace(d.json_data,'\"', '"') from  json_logs d where d.json_data like '%Error%'; but no luck

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your string has escaped single quotes, `\'`. But you are doung

```
replace(d.json_data,'\"', '"')
```

which is looking for escaped double quotes, `\"`.

So you need to use:

```
replace(d.json_data,'\''', '''')
```

which also doubles-up the single quotes within the search and replacement strings, to perform Oracle's own escape of those.

You could also use the alternative quoting mechanism:

```
replace(d.json_data,q'[\']', q'[']')
```

but I'm not sure that's a lot clearer in this case.

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=7472b53c6500d27e5eeba0ef837c6bed)

Comment: : for below its giving error :
  insert into  execution_log(err_message) 
values(
 replace(replace("Database Error in model customer (models\customer.sql)
  000904 (42000): SQL compilation error: error line 126 at position 2
  invalid identifier 'CC.name1'",'\'', ''''),'\'')
 )
  ;
=>Error: invalid identifier '"Database Error in model customer(models\customer.sql)
 Can you suggest what is wrong ?

Comment: You have double quotes (`"`) around your string literal instead of single quotes (`'`). As that string also *contains* single quotes you will need to escape those, or use the alternative quoting syntax. I don't understand what you're doing though - you are replacing JSON-escaped quotes with SQL-escaped quotes, even though you don't have any; and then replace again when you  have already replace any that exist.

Comment: How can I escape inner single quotes? I want to insert line "Database Error in model customer (models\customer.sql) 000904 (42000): SQL compilation error: error line 126 at position 2 invalid identifier 'CC.name1'" in my table. but due to these in-between signal quotes, I am facing errors

Comment: Like I said, escaping or using alternative quoting syntax - [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Jh7Grmfk).